# No response from server running in Docker container within LAN

Tags: node.js, docker, networking

I'm not sure if this is a networking issue, or a Docker issue, but I'm having a difficult time getting a response from a server on a separate machine in my LAN that is running a nodejs server on port 3000 in a Docker container. I'm using a Mac computer as a client, and a Linux computer as a server. These are the steps I've taken :

**Testing connection to separate computer on LAN using `<name of computer>.local:<port>`**

- Run server on Linux machine (just using nodejs without a container)
- On Mac (client) computer run `curl <name of linux computer>.local:3000`
- Works as expected

**Testing connection to server on localhost while running inside of a Docker container**

- Run server on Linux machine inside of a container using the command `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 <name of image>`
- On Linux machine run `curl localhost:3000`
- Works as expected

**Testing connection to separate computer while running server in Docker container**

- Run server on Linux machine inside of a container using the command `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 <name of image>`
- On mac machine run `curl <name of linux computer>.local:3000`
- No response from server

Answer (score 1):

The container will not be accessable external to the Linux host when listening on `127.0.0.1`/`localhost`.

To bind to all available interfaces use:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 <image>
```

Or specify the address of a publicly available interface from `ip address show`

```
docker run -p <public_ip>:3000:3000 <image>
```